# Regex fall through in Java

Tags: java, regex, expression

I am having trouble developing a regex pattern in Java to split a university timetable class string.

An example string is like this:

```
"CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab1: 05:11:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] (cont) CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab2: 07:19:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] (cont) "
```

(It is all one line)

Using the regex pattern:

```
final String classregex = "(?<=\\(cont\\)\\s|\\[Pref \\d{1,2}\\]\\s)";
```

It should split into exactly two class entries:

```
"CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab1: 05:11:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] (cont) "
"CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab2: 07:19:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] (cont) "
```

The zero-length look behind is intended; I want to retain all data.

Instead I get:

```
"CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab1: 05:11:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] "
"(cont) "
"CIVL4401_SEM-1:Laboratory_Lab2: 07:19:Engineering - Civil & Mechanical: Soils Lab (G99): [Pref 1] "
"(cont) "
```

Which I'm pretty sure I understand why this is happening - it matches the "[Pref d]" first, extracts that string out, then goes through the rest, finding "(cont)" immediately after and so on.

Note that there are also timetable classes which have no "(cont)" in them, so that is why there is a "[Pref d]" part in the regex.

Is there some way to order how the Java regex engine works? I want it to try to match the "(cont)" first before trying to match the "[Pref d]" part. My guess is there would have to be a complicated look ahead and look behind expression which I am not sure how to go about.

If this can't be done then I will go about writing up a fix function to deal with this. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using an alternation instead of just `(?<=\\[Pref \\d{1,2}\\]\\s\\(cont\\)\\s)`? You want to split on `[Pref 1] (cont)`, right?

Comment: @Robin it says in the question that sometimes the (cont) part is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
(?<=\(cont\)\s|\[Pref\s\d\]\s(?!\(cont\)))
```

It would additionally check that `[Pref \d]` is not followed by a `(cont)`

In Java world that would be:

```
(?<=\\(cont\\)\\s|\\[Pref\\s\\d\\]\\s(?!\\(cont\\)))
```

but I was surprised to find even this is working

```
(?<=\\(cont\\)\\s|\\[Pref\\s\\d{1,2}\\]\\s(?!\\(cont\\)))
```

As mentioned by OP in comments it seems Java supports finite range quantifiers in lookbehinds. Here is an extract from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`Java takes things a step further by allowing finite repetition. You still cannot use the star or plus, but you can use the question mark and the curly braces with the max parameter specified. Java determines the minimum and maximum possible lengths of the lookbehind. The lookbehind in the regex (?<!ab{2,4}c{3,5}d)test has 6 possible lengths. It can be between 7 to 11 characters long. When Java (version 6 or later) tries to match the lookbehind, it first steps back the minimum number of characters (7 in this example) in the string and then evaluates the regex inside the lookbehind as usual, from left to right. If it fails, Java steps back one more character and tries again. If the lookbehind continues to fail, Java continues to step back until the lookbehind either matches or it has stepped back the maximum number of characters (11 in this example). This repeated stepping back through the subject string kills performance when the number of possible lengths of the lookbehind grows. Keep this in mind. Don't choose an arbitrarily large maximum number of repetitions to work around the lack of infinite quantifiers inside lookbehind. Java 4 and 5 have bugs that cause lookbehind with alternation or variable quantifiers to fail when it should succeed in some situations. These bugs were fixed in Java 6.`

Comment: Edit for your other comment: I actually came across that problem before as well... I had initially \\d+ as the expression but I found it wasn't working - turns out it was exactly that; the regex engines I use dont support that. However I believe I read somewhere that the Java one supports a finite range.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the '?' conditional as per http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 ?

I believe adding (\(cont\))? would work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went with the answer above (which is sort of similar to yours).